# Why won't the Control Center module let me turn on Airdrop on my iphone 8?

Tags: iphone, airdrop, control-center

This has worked before in the past but I don't know why it doesn't work now.

I used to be able to turn Airdrop on/off on my iphone by:

1. Swiping up from the bottom of my phone
2. Pressing and holding the module that has options for Airplane mode, WiFi, etc. (image of what I'm talking about [here on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20turn%20on%20airdrop%20on%20iphone%208&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=VD4CF_uZiogmOM%253A%252CFe7FCbYcRZwiZM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kRZIfTQ2TqGaJX0riiY6G2g0uZIpg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEy8CP-avjAhWhITQIHULqBOwQ9QEwAHoECAUQAw&biw=1566&bih=771#imgrc=VD4CF_uZiogmOM:))

For some reason, now when I press and hold that module, it doesn't open up to let me turn Airdrop on/off or turn on my personal hotspot.

I've tried powering off/on my phone, and closing all apps but nothing is working.  I don't know what else to try.  Is there some app that I installed that might have prevented this from working as usual?  What can I do to make this simple function work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange.  It seems like some random bit got inverted on my iphone (just a joke but still seems weird).  I have to turn off 3D Touch to get the modules to expand again.

This is how I got it to work.  I went to Settings->General->Accessibility->3D Touch and turned it off.  After doing this, the module with Airplane mode, Wifi enable, etc now expand.

I found this [link from the apple discussion website](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8425831).  After reading this posting, I turned off my 3D Touch and it worked.  Again, my wife's phone is the same everything as my phone (iphone 8 with IOS 11.4 loaded) and hers works with 3D Touch still on so something weird happened with my phone.  The only thing I can think of is some app was installed that made this stop working.  If I find which app, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

What version of iOS are you running? If it’s a version that supports screen time I would try disabling and reenabling airdrop from screen time menu within the settings app

Comment: I'm running 11.4.  My wife is also running 11.4 but the module opens up for her to easily enable/disable Airdrop.